# Need to find limit, given function

Tags: limits, functions

Given that

1. $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all real $x, y$
2. $f(1) = 1$.

To show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$$

My intuition says that (1) gives us $f(x) = cx$ for some real $c$ ; but I am unable to argue why that should be.

**Edit:**

My actual question is to evaluate below :

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2^{f(\tan x)} - 2^{f(\sin x)} }{x^2 f(\sin x) } $$

Which evaluates assuming $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ approaches $~1~$ as $~x~$ approaches to $~0~$.

Comment: On second thoughts, f(x) perhaps need not be cx. A function that is identity for rationals, and 0 for irrationals also seems to satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Well, the function **is** $\;f(x)=cx\;$ ...under the assumption the function is *continuous*, something you didn't write.

Comment: The continuity of function isn't given in the question I am solving.

Comment: The is the functional equation by Cauchy.

Comment: Note that $f(r)=r$ for all $r\in \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Riemann how about $f(-1)$ ?

Comment: I added the entire question, does this help?

Comment: @Fareed, it is an odd function (can be shown by taking $y = -x$, along with $f(0) = 0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist discontinous functions satisfying the given conditions. Such functions are not bounded in any neighborhood of $0$ so they do not satisfy $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x)} x=1$. So the result, as stated, is false. However, if $f$ is continuous then the first condition implies that $f(x)=cx$ for some $c$ and the second condition implies that $c=1$ so we are done. A proof of the fact that if $f$ is continuous then  $f(x)=cx$ for some $c$ can be found easily by searching for Cauchy's Functional Equation.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that from $(1)$ you can conclude that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{f(1)}{n}$ which by $(2)$ equals $\frac{1}{n}$. From this you can conclude that if the limit in the question exists, it must be $1$.

Unfortunately, the limit may not exists without further assumptions on $f$.

Consider the set $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,...\}$. This is a set of independent real numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so we can extend it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the unique linear map which takes $\pi^k$ to $4^k$ and every other element in the basis to zero.

Then $f(1) = f(\pi^0) = 4^0 = 1$ so $(1),(2)$ are satisfied.

However $f(\pi^k) = 4^k$ and so $f( \frac{1}{4^k} \pi^k)/\frac{1}{4^k}\pi^k = (\frac{4}{\pi})^k$ does not converge to $1$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

Edit: As mentioned by @kavi Rama Murty, the conclusion becomes true if you assume that $f$ is continuout. In fact, given assumption $(1)$ it is enough to assume that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable (as any measurable homomorphism is continuous). In particular this means that you can't construct a counter-example without using the axiom of choice.